# How to use a UIImage as a mask over a color in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a UIImage that is all black with an alpha channel so some parts are grayish and some parts are completely see-through. I want to use that images as a mask over some other color (let's say white to make it easy), so the final product is now a white image with parts of it transparent.

I've been looking around on the Apple documentation site here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHIJEB

But I don't can't really make sense of those examples.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*In iOS 7+ you should use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965557/870313*

---

Creating arbitrarily-colored icons from a black-with-alpha master image (iOS).

```
// Usage: UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage ipMaskedImageNamed:@"UIButtonBarAction.png" color:[UIColor redColor]];

+ (UIImage *)ipMaskedImageNamed:(NSString *)name color:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, image.scale);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Credits to Ole Zorn: https://gist.github.com/1102091

Comment: Worth noting. If you are using UIImageView to display the image, here's a simple solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26965557/870313

Answer (score 4):

Translating Jano's answer into Swift:

```
func ipMaskedImageNamed(name:String, color:UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let image = UIImage(named: name)
    let rect:CGRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: image!.size.width, height: image!.size.height))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, image!.scale)
    let c:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    image?.drawInRect(rect)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, color.CGColor)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop)
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect)
    let result:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
myButton.setImage(ipMaskedImageNamed("grayScalePNG", color: UIColor.redColor()), forState: .Normal)
```

**Edit**: According to this [article](http://krakendev.io/blog/4-xcode-asset-catalog-secrets-you-need-to-know), you can turn an image into a mask whose opaque areas are represented by the tint color.  Within the asset catalog, under the **Attributes Inspector** of the image, change **Render As** to **Template Image**.  No code necessary.

Comment: The Asset Catalog solution seems like the real solution these days. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation in Swift 3, written as an extension to UIImage:

```
extension UIImage {
    func tinted(color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let image = self
        let rect:CGRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, image.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        image.draw(in: rect)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.setBlendMode(.sourceAtop)
        context.fill(rect)
        if let result:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return result
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// Usage
let myImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Check.png") // any image
let blueImage = myImage.tinted(color: .blue)
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted this for OSX [here](https://gist.github.com/barchard/8227332) as a Category and copied below. Note this is for non-ARC projects. For ARC projects, the autorelease can be removed.

```
- (NSImage *)cdsMaskedWithColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    NSImage *result = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    [result lockFocusFlipped:self.isFlipped];

    NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef c = (CGContextRef)[context graphicsPort];

    [self drawInRect:NSRectFromCGRect(rect)];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
    CGContextFillRect(c, rect);

    [result unlockFocus];

    return [result autorelease];
}
+ (NSImage *)cdsMaskedImageNamed:(NSString *)name color:(NSColor *)color
{
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:name];
    return [image cdsMaskedWithColor:color];
}
```