# While images painted by colors from UIColor and colorsWithRed … look different (bad in second case)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I paint gray circle in colors:

[image]

for painting I use this method: [Is that possible to change the color for an image programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771601/is-that-possible-to-change-the-color-for-an-image-programmatically/21772285#21772285)

So circles above Fuel and Penalty look good - I use standard colors from UIColor (greenColor and redColor)
But circle above Washing looks terrible - I use

```
  [UIColor colorWithRed:143.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:66.0/255.0 alpha:1]
```

One source image colored by different colors:

```
fuelCircle.image = [Colors useColor:[UIColor greenColor] forImage:fuelCircle.image];
washingCircle.image = [Colors useColor:[Colors green] forImage:washingCircle.image];
penaltyCircle.image = [Colors useColor:[UIColor redColor] forImage:penaltyCircle.image];
```

How can I set my colors which will look perfect?

UPD:
If I use color [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1]; Washings circle will be look like Fuel. So, maybe I need find right color balance.

Comment: What does washing look like if you use UIColor redColor?

Comment: Did you make sure that the raw image without border is perfectly transparent?

Comment: It will look like Penalty (about circles)

Comment: Here is only one raw image colored by three different colors - 2 standard and 1 setted by user