# Image from color issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uicolor

i am using the method below:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

from the [link](https://github.com/NZN/UIImage-Helpers/blob/master/UIImage-Helpers/UIImage%2BImageWithColor.m) . My issue is that the image returned has not the same color in parameter.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more "the image returned has not the same color in parameter"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292212/changing-the-color-of-image-in-iphone-sdkf

Comment: for example the input color is [UIColor colorWithRed:219./255. green:94./255. blue:8./255. alpha:1.] the returned image has the code R:208 G:73 B:12

Comment: How are you checking that it's not the same color?

Comment: i checked this with the colorimeter application in mac os, and the difference is noticeable without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by replacing `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);` with `[color setFill];` the new method will be like the code below:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageFromColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```