# Replace color in uiimage with another color

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-image

Is there an API that I could use (perhaps in coreimage) to change all pixels of a specific color to another color?  I think I can figure out how to do it manually by iterating through each pixel of the image, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant (and higher performance) way to accomplish this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872680/changing-uiimage-color and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396236/ios-change-the-colors-of-a-uiimage/12399760#12399760

Comment: Thanks, but I had already seen these threads before I posted and neither is quite what I had in mind. The first is using the image as a mask, which is the same as the below suggestion by Kirit.  The second is manually iterating through every pixel. Isn't here a more efficient way to do his that leverages the GPU?

Answer (score 3):

your Image color is replace by red color a below code

**Your Original image code:**

```
UIImageView *image1 =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Lock.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:image1];
```

**Rad Color image code**

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.frame.size.width, image1.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lock.png"].CGImage);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage *flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                                            scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

image1.image = flippedImage;
```

**Original image**

[image]

**Red color image**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I might be able to break up my source image into several mask images, and then use this code to do what I want, but this isn't quite what I had in mind.  I'm looking for a method like: changeColor(UIImage* img, UIColor* fromColor, UIColor* toColor) that I could use to, for example, change all the blue in an image of an American flag, to green.

Comment: the white section is transparent, so the code change blue to red.but is the white section is UIColor white... the image will become a red one.....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Core Image filter CIColorCube for that. I haven't used it before, but I believe it lets you map ranges of input colors to different output colors.

Comment: Here's an example of how to do what @Duncan mentioned in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32638622/1807644