# Change image in UIImageView when row is selected?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, uicolor

This is how item looks when it is selected.

[image]

Normally row has black background, and icon has white foreground. But selecting a row will made background semi white. Is it a way to change image to opposite color, or use a different image in `imageView` when `imageView`'s row is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @NSDmitry's example, you need to override `setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` on the `UITableViewCell` and set the `tintColor` of the whole `contentView` or just the `imageView`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, UIImageView color can be set, using highlighted image. It has two types of properties to images. Normal and Highlighted image.

This options are available in attribute inspector in Interface file (storyboard/XIB).

Another option is available for vector images, where you can set tintColor for template types of image asset.

**Swift**
You can also set both properties programatically.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(<set your initialiser>)
imageView.image = //Your normal image
imageView.highlightedImage = //You highligted image
```

Upon your tableview row selection status, change state of image from normal to highlighted and vice-versa. imageView.isHighlighted = true/false

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageView.isHighlighted = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageView.isHighlighted = false
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer to this question [Changing UIImage color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872680/changing-uiimage-color/26965557#26965557)

You should declare your image as the mask(`.alwaysTemplate`) then you can change `tintColor` for any `UIColor`.